# Java - Using PowerMockito to Mock LocalDate.now()

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermockito, localdate

Need to create a unit test for a function which relies on LocalDate.now(). I have attempted to mock the system time using PowerMockito. It is not feasible to change the code to remove the dependency on LocalDate.now(), or to use any alternatives to PowerMockito.

When LocalDate.now() is called directly from the unit test, it works and returns the mocked timestamp. However, when called via the function in question, the mock fails and the normal system time is returned. Anyone know why this discrepancy occurs?

**Unit Test**

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ LocalDate.class })
public class FunctionInvolvingLocalDateNowTest {
    @Test
    public void functionInvolvingLocalDateNowTest() {
        Clock clock = Clock.fixed(Instant.parse("2020-06-02T00:00:00.00Z"), ZoneId.of("UTC"));
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now(clock);

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(LocalDate.class);
        PowerMockito.when(LocalDate.now()).thenReturn(date);
        PowerMockito.when(LocalDate.of(Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyInt())).thenCallRealMethod();

        //LocalDate.now() returns mocked time when called directly from unit test
        LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
        
        LocalDate testDate = LocalDate.of(2020, 6, 2);
        
        //LocalDate.now() does not return mocked time when called within this function
        LocalDate result = DateUtils.functionInvolvingLocalDateNow(testDate);
        
        Assert.assertEquals("2020-04-30", result.toString());
    }
}
```

**Function involving LocalDate.now()**

```
public static LocalDate functionInvolvingLocalDateNow(LocalDate inputDate) {
    LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now();
    
    //Other logic
    ...
}
```

Comment: In `@PrepareForTest` try to also add the class of the function that you are calling.

Comment: mock fails because you use a static method

Answer (score 0):

Any time you see "mock" and "static" together, that is a sign of a serious design problem. In this case, the `functionInvolvingLocalDateNow` depends on *hidden state* (the system clock), and it's not deterministic. Instead, it should most likely be an instance method on a containing class that has a `Clock` variable. (Alternately, it might stay a static method but take an explicit `Clock` parameter, but this gets cumbersome.)

A better design looks like this:

```
public class ClockUser {
    private Clock clock = Clock.systemUTC();

    public void setClock(Clock clock) {
        this.clock = clock;
    }

    public LocalDate functionInvolvingLocalDateNow(LocalDate input) {
        LocalDate current = LocalDate.now(clock);
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that in the case where there's an obvious default implementation, like "use the system clock", it's perfectly fine to use a field initializer and not have to pass the default in the constructor.